# Can't see photos when using Droid Explorer

Tags: droid-explorer

I have Huawei Ascend Y550. It is rooted and I can see, edit, and change files with a root explorer app. However, I have difficulty doing the same in Droid Explorer. I am using Droid Explorer because no matter what I try, I can't seem to get my work PC to recognise and get access to my phone. I have tried all sorts of things, and the phone is recognised on another work PC but not on the one I use.

I'm new to Droid Explorer. I have followed all the instructions, installed it, and able to view my files and SD card as well, but I cannot see photos in the DCIM folder.

I can see the .thumbnails, 100ANDRO, and Camera folders inside the DCIM folder. When I go into the Camera folder, I can see the folders I have created that contain the specific photos. But when I get into each of those, there is nothing shown inside.

Here are the log files from Droid Explorer:

- http://www.mediafire.com/download/inml7ubbdbhf518/Harold_Debug_Log_28.2.16.log
- http://www.mediafire.com/download/1lxi7ss3aa7q8b8/DroidExplorer20160221.log20160221.log
- http://www.mediafire.com/download/mxqhaznag62anat/DroidExplorer20160227.log
- http://www.mediafire.com/download/xchike02rs9l9xq/DroidExplorer20160228.log
- http://www.mediafire.com/download/inml7ubbdbhf518/Harold_Debug_Log_28.2.16.log

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log files, I will say this is a bug, but I have a potential workaround for now.

The problem is the `'`. If you rename the folder without the `'`, you should not have a problem seeing the photos.